# Define custom days in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate

I would like to define the times at which a day starts and ends.

For example, lets assume that I don't want a new day to start until 10am the following day.

For sample data I have the following:

```
                    dt
1  2015-01-01 10:45:00
2  2015-01-01 11:30:00
3  2015-01-01 11:45:00
4  2015-01-01 12:00:00
5  2015-01-01 12:30:00
6  2015-01-01 13:00:00
7  2015-01-01 14:30:00
8  2015-01-01 15:00:00
9  2015-01-01 16:30:00
10 2015-01-01 16:45:00
11 2015-01-01 18:15:00
12 2015-01-01 18:45:00
13 2015-01-01 19:15:00
14 2015-01-01 21:45:00
15 2015-01-01 22:00:00
16 2015-01-01 23:00:00
17 2015-01-01 23:15:00
18 2015-01-02 00:00:00
19 2015-01-02 11:45:00
20 2015-01-02 17:00:00
21 2015-01-02 18:00:00
22 2015-01-02 19:15:00
23 2015-01-02 21:30:00
24 2015-01-02 21:45:00
25 2015-01-02 22:45:00
```

A `dput()` of this data can be copied into R.

```
data <- structure(list(dt = structure(c(1420111800, 1420127100, 1420129800, 
1420133400, 1420149600, 1420150500, 1420154100, 1420155900, 1420157700, 
1420200000, 1420203600, 1420206300, 1420209000, 1420215300, 1420218000, 
1420224300, 1420229700, 1420231500, 1420234200, 1420236900, 1420239600, 
1420240500, 1420241400, 1420244100, 1420245900), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame")
```

The only way I have calcualted the day of week in the past is with `lubridate::wday` as follows

```
data %>% 
  mutate(dow = wday(dt, label = T))

                    dt dow
1  2015-01-01 11:30:00 Thu
2  2015-01-01 15:45:00 Thu
3  2015-01-01 16:30:00 Thu
4  2015-01-01 17:30:00 Thu
5  2015-01-01 22:00:00 Thu
6  2015-01-01 22:15:00 Thu
7  2015-01-01 23:15:00 Thu
8  2015-01-01 23:45:00 Thu
9  2015-01-02 00:15:00 Fri # make Thu
10 2015-01-02 12:00:00 Fri
11 2015-01-02 13:00:00 Fri 
12 2015-01-02 13:45:00 Fri 
13 2015-01-02 14:30:00 Fri 
14 2015-01-02 16:15:00 Fri 
15 2015-01-02 17:00:00 Fri 
16 2015-01-02 18:45:00 Fri 
17 2015-01-02 20:15:00 Fri
18 2015-01-02 20:45:00 Fri
19 2015-01-02 21:30:00 Fri
20 2015-01-02 22:15:00 Fri
21 2015-01-02 23:00:00 Fri
22 2015-01-02 23:15:00 Fri
23 2015-01-02 23:30:00 Fri
24 2015-01-03 00:15:00 Sat # make Fri
25 2015-01-03 00:45:00 Sat # make Fri
```

I marked the days that would be incorrect if assuming a new day does not start until 10am the next day.

I was curious what options are available for defining the times for which a new day starts/ends.

Comment: It looks like you're intentionally defining the points in UTC, though looking for days to be defined off of Hawaii or Tahiti time. Is that meaningful? Are you really trying to define days off of the UTC-10 time zone?

Comment: I think thinking more of a situation where you have a business such as a bar or club where defining sales to end at midnight does not make much sense for their application. Defining open/close times makes more sense than 0 to 24 hundred hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lacking timezone changes, I'd think your best bet is to `if_else` off of the hour of the day, similar to what you're doing now:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
data %>%
  mutate(
    dow = wday(dt, label = T),
    dow2 = wday(dt - if_else(hour(dt) < 11, 86400, 0), label = TRUE)
  )
#                     dt dow dow2
# 1  2015-01-01 11:30:00 Thu  Thu
# 2  2015-01-01 15:45:00 Thu  Thu
# 3  2015-01-01 16:30:00 Thu  Thu
# 4  2015-01-01 17:30:00 Thu  Thu
# 5  2015-01-01 22:00:00 Thu  Thu
# 6  2015-01-01 22:15:00 Thu  Thu
# 7  2015-01-01 23:15:00 Thu  Thu
# 8  2015-01-01 23:45:00 Thu  Thu
# 9  2015-01-02 00:15:00 Fri  Thu
# 10 2015-01-02 12:00:00 Fri  Fri
# 11 2015-01-02 13:00:00 Fri  Fri
# 12 2015-01-02 13:45:00 Fri  Fri
# 13 2015-01-02 14:30:00 Fri  Fri
# 14 2015-01-02 16:15:00 Fri  Fri
# 15 2015-01-02 17:00:00 Fri  Fri
# 16 2015-01-02 18:45:00 Fri  Fri
# 17 2015-01-02 20:15:00 Fri  Fri
# 18 2015-01-02 20:45:00 Fri  Fri
# 19 2015-01-02 21:30:00 Fri  Fri
# 20 2015-01-02 22:15:00 Fri  Fri
# 21 2015-01-02 23:00:00 Fri  Fri
# 22 2015-01-02 23:15:00 Fri  Fri
# 23 2015-01-02 23:30:00 Fri  Fri
# 24 2015-01-03 00:15:00 Sat  Fri
# 25 2015-01-03 00:45:00 Sat  Fri
```

(This `if_else` is rather trivial and can be shortened to `wday(dt - 86400*(hour(dt) < 11), label = TRUE)`.)

Answer (score 1):

Using `base`

```
data$dow <- with(data, ifelse(strftime(dt, "%H") < 11, 
                  strftime(dt - as.difftime(1, units = "days"), "%a"), 
                  strftime(dt, "%a")
                  )
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this will get you there:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(
    dt1 = dt - hours(10),
    dow = wday(dt1, label = T))

                    dt                 dt1 dow
1  2015-01-01 11:30:00 2015-01-01 01:30:00 Thu
2  2015-01-01 15:45:00 2015-01-01 05:45:00 Thu
3  2015-01-01 16:30:00 2015-01-01 06:30:00 Thu
4  2015-01-01 17:30:00 2015-01-01 07:30:00 Thu
5  2015-01-01 22:00:00 2015-01-01 12:00:00 Thu
6  2015-01-01 22:15:00 2015-01-01 12:15:00 Thu
7  2015-01-01 23:15:00 2015-01-01 13:15:00 Thu
8  2015-01-01 23:45:00 2015-01-01 13:45:00 Thu
9  2015-01-02 00:15:00 2015-01-01 14:15:00 Thu
10 2015-01-02 12:00:00 2015-01-02 02:00:00 Fri
11 2015-01-02 13:00:00 2015-01-02 03:00:00 Fri
12 2015-01-02 13:45:00 2015-01-02 03:45:00 Fri
13 2015-01-02 14:30:00 2015-01-02 04:30:00 Fri
14 2015-01-02 16:15:00 2015-01-02 06:15:00 Fri
15 2015-01-02 17:00:00 2015-01-02 07:00:00 Fri
16 2015-01-02 18:45:00 2015-01-02 08:45:00 Fri
17 2015-01-02 20:15:00 2015-01-02 10:15:00 Fri
18 2015-01-02 20:45:00 2015-01-02 10:45:00 Fri
19 2015-01-02 21:30:00 2015-01-02 11:30:00 Fri
20 2015-01-02 22:15:00 2015-01-02 12:15:00 Fri
21 2015-01-02 23:00:00 2015-01-02 13:00:00 Fri
22 2015-01-02 23:15:00 2015-01-02 13:15:00 Fri
23 2015-01-02 23:30:00 2015-01-02 13:30:00 Fri
24 2015-01-03 00:15:00 2015-01-02 14:15:00 Fri
25 2015-01-03 00:45:00 2015-01-02 14:45:00 Fri
```